# How to plot large trees with R package partykit?

Tags: r, plot, classification

If have a data set with 50000 observations for 27 explanatory variables (both categorical and metric) and one binary response variable.

When creating a classification tree with `rpart` (CART-algorithm), I get a pruned tree with 27 terminal nodes.

When creating a decision tree with chaid (CHAID-algorithm), I get a tree with round about 100 terminal nodes. (Of course, I transformed metric data into categorical data).  This also happens when using `partykit` (with conditional inference trees and `mincriterion = 0.999`).

For all algorithms `minsplit=150` and `minbucket=50`.

How can I plot trees with about 100 terminal nodes? I thought about maybe only plotting the ID of the terminal nodes and then showing summary statistics of the terminal nodes seperately. I tried to do this with the following code (where chaid is an object of class party):

```
plot(chaid, type="simple",gp = gpar(fontsize = 10), drop=T, 
ip_args=list(abbreviate = F, id = F, pval=F), tp_args=list(id=T))
```

But it doesn't work as I get even more summary statistics for terminal nodes as without the `tp_args` argument. How can I plot only the ID of the terminal node? Or does anybody have any ideas/ examples how to print such large trees?

Is it even possible that a data set of this size results in such a large tree or did I miss anything?

Comment: Have you considered using the data.tree package. It is pretty easy to decide what is printed in those. You can just gather the wanted printouts as as string, and then place them in the nodes.